# how to send push notification from onesignal the device id's are stored in database - cordova app

Tags: php, android, ios, cordova, push-notification

I'm using push notification from onesignal platform in my *cordova* app. I have implemented it to send push notification from oneSignal dashboard but I want to send notification from my own search, I have stored device ids when user install the app but don't know how to send notifications to devices that's ids are stored in my database

Any help regarding this will be appreciated . Thanks if anyone has issue to understand my question can comment i will explain with my best capacity.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this case, I also use one signal, but at the launch of my app, I send my id to my backend to be sure it will be registered to my db when I will need it. Just with a classic http post request.

There is no magic trick to achieve that, you don't have lot of choices here except save it to your db by a way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function which is provided by [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/reference#section-send-based-on-onesignal-playerids-create-notification)

```
function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_MESSAGE'
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "YOUR_APP_ID",
        'include_player_ids' => array("YOUR_TARGET_ID"),
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode( $return);

print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");
```